# zombiefied threads in ps (for a threaded program written in c)

Tags: c, pthreads, zombie-process

I am afraid I am not sure what I'm doing wrong here.
I have a threaded application that starts 3 threads upon start

```
[root@Embest /]# ps 
1111 root        608 S   fw634c_d_cdm_sb
1112 root        608 S   fw634c_d_cdm_sb
1113 root        608 S   fw634c_d_cdm_sb
```

then waits in standby mode for commands from the serial.
after it runs and returns to stand by mode, I check with ps whats going on; there are zombiefied instances of the application (and the file name is sq.bracketed too)

```
1114 root            Z   [fw634c_d_cdm_sb]
...
...
...
1768 root            Z   [fw634c_d_cdm_sb]
```

about 628 of them.

thing is,
the policy i'm following is:

-for detachable threads - don't care (they will exit and free resources on their own after completing)

-for joinable threads - i run pthread_join after running  pthread_create and wait for the threaded function to complete. like this:

```
        if (pthread_create(&tmp_thrd_id,&attr_joinable,run_function,(void *)&aStruct)!=0){
            DEBUG(printf("thread NOT created \n"));
        }else{
            DEBUG(printf("thread created !\n"));

            if (pthread_join(tmp_thrd_id,NULL)!=0){ 
                DEBUG(printf("\nERROR in joining \n"));
            }else{
                            DEBUG(printf("Thread completed\n"));
            }
        }
```

I only run pthread_exit(NULL) in main , which doesn't do much and after the startup just lies around just because it must not be killed.

i'm probably forgeting something vital here. but can't clarify what after reading a few basic guides on threads....

thank you for your help

Comment: 600 threads ? Are you calling `pthread_create` somewhere else ?

Comment: What OS are you on? Judging from some of the bogus pthread behavior and ps output you've observed, I'm going to guess Linux 2.4 with LinuxThreads, but this should really be part of the question...

Comment: @cnicutar yes in a few parts of the code threads are created.

Comment: @R.. bingo, the OS is kernel 2.4 on an ARM board. I'm running gdbserver on the board and connect through serial to gdb (btw (gdb) threads info shows only 3 threads when the ps shows the 60+ zombies)

Comment: Well if you're using LinuxThreads, one of the difficult things to deal with is that you don't really have POSIX threads; you have an API that looks superficially like pthreads but with radically different (and IMO broken) behavior. I think the Linux man page for `pthreads` describes some of what's wrong with LinuxThreads, but for ugly behavior like this you might have to dig into the sources...

Comment: @R.. hmm i had no idea about that.. how can I verify whether I am using Linuxthreads or pthreads?

Comment: If you're on Linux 2.4, you're using LinuxThreads. Linux 2.4 was way too broken on the kernel side to support a conformant pthreads implementation.

Answer (score 0):

A "zombie" thread is a thread that has exited, and is waiting around for someone to call pthread_join to collect its exit status.  So somewhere in your program you are creating threads and not eventually calling pthread_join or pthread_detach for those threads.

Comment: that was my initial assumption too, but I double checked the code. In the end it was due to a libraries mismatch that the error was caused.